# How to fix "the following classes have no ground truth examples" when running object_detection/model_main.py?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have defined a `pascal_label_map.pbtext` with 824 classes to create `TFRecord` files from my JPEG dataset with Pascal VOC style annotations with `create_pascal_tf_record.py`.
The script seems to generate these `TFRecords` correctly (e.g. I checked that all classes from `pascal_label_map.pbtext` occur in the annotations and that each JPEG comes with the correct annotation). But when I start `object_detection/model_main.py` I see the following:

```
WARNING:root:The following classes have no ground truth examples: 
[
   2   3   5   7   9  10  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
  25  26  27  30  35  36  37  38  40  42  43  44  47  48  49  51  52  53
  55  58  59  60  61  62  64  65  69  70  71  73  74  75  77  78  79  81
  82  84  85  86  87  88  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101
 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119
 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137
 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155
 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173
 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191
 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209
 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227
 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245
 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263
 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278 279 280 281
 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290 291 292 293 294 295 296 297 298 299
 300 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 308 309 310 311 312 313 314 315 316 317
 318 319 320 321 322 323 324 325 326 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335
 336 337 338 339 340 341 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 350 351 352 353
 354 355 356 357 358 359 360 361 362 363 364 365 366 367 368 369 370 371
 372 373 374 375 376 377 378 379 380 381 382 383 384 385 386 387 388 389
 390 391 392 393 394 395 396 397 398 399 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407
 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 419 420 421 422 423 424 425
 426 427 428 429 430 431 432 433 434 435 436 437 438 439 440 441 442 443
 444 445 446 447 448 449 450 451 452 453 454 455 456 457 458 459 460 461
 462 463 464 465 466 467 468 469 470 471 472 473 474 475 476 477 478 479
 480 481 482 483 484 485 486 487 488 489 490 491 492 493 494 495 496 497
 498 499 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 512 513 514 515
 516 517 518 519 520 521 522 523 524 525 526 527 528 529 530 531 532 533
 534 535 536 537 538 539 540 541 542 543 544 545 546 547 548 549 550 551
 552 553 554 555 556 557 558 559 560 561 562 563 564 565 566 567 568 569
 570 571 572 573 574 575 576 577 578 579 580 581 582 583 584 585 586 587
 588 589 590 591 592 593 594 595 596 597 598 599 600 601 602 603 604 605
 606 607 608 609 610 611 612 613 614 615 616 617 618 619 620 621 622 623
 624 625 626 627 628 629 630 631 632 633 634 635 636 637 638 639 640 641
 642 643 644 645 646 647 648 649 650 651 652 653 654 655 656 657 658 659
 660 661 662 663 664 665 666 667 668 669 670 671 672 673 674 675 676 677
 678 679 680 681 682 683 684 685 686 687 688 689 690 691 692 693 694 695
 696 697 698 699 700 701 702 703 704 705 706 707 708 709 710 711 712 713
 714 715 716 717 718 719 720 721 722 723 724 725 726 727 728 729 730 731
 732 733 734 735 736 737 738 739 740 741 742 743 744 745 746 747 748 749
 750 751 752 753 754 755 756 757 758 759 760 761 762 763 764 765 766 767
 768 769 770 771 772 773 774 775 776 777 778 779 780 781 782 783 784 785
 786 787 788 789 790 791 792 793 794 795 796 797 798 799 800 801 802 803
 804 805 806 807 808 809 810 811 812 813 814 815 816 817 818 819 820 821
 822 823 824]
```

How can I fix this?

I have tried both `python2.7` and `python3.7` (installed with anaconda in bash on Ubuntu in Windows). Instead of `model_main.py` I tried `object_detection/legacy/train.py` and `object_detection/legacy/eval.py`. 
`train.py` seemed to run correctly.

When I opened tensorboard after running `train.py` and `eval.py`, I noticed that neither the images had any object detection boxes nor any correct ground-truth. Expect for one or two cases, the incorrect ground truth label was the one corresponding to 1 in `pascal_label_map.pbtext`.
The bounding box coordinates are correct though.

---

This is my model .config file (with the right pathes of course):

```
model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 821
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 600
        max_dimension: 1024
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'faster_rcnn_inception_v2'
      first_stage_features_stride: 16
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        scales: [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        aspect_ratios: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        height_stride: 16
        width_stride: 16
      }
    }
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.01
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.7
    first_stage_max_proposals: 300
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    initial_crop_size: 14
    maxpool_kernel_size: 2
    maxpool_stride: 2
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 1.0
        fc_hyperparams {
          op: FC
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            variance_scaling_initializer {
              factor: 1.0
              uniform: true
              mode: FAN_AVG
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.0
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 300
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
  }
}
train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        manual_step_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0002
          schedule {
            step: 900000
            learning_rate: .00002
          }
          schedule {
            step: 1200000
            learning_rate: .000002
          }
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0
  #fine_tune_checkpoint: "PATH_TO/models/model/model.ckpt"
  #from_detection_checkpoint: true
  #load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars: true
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps,         which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the COCO         dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate     will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 5000

  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_vertical_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_rotation90 {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "PATH_TO/data/pascal_label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path:"PATH_TO/data/pascal_train.record-?????-of-00010"
  }
}
eval_config {
  num_examples: 1886
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 100     evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 1886
  #use_moving_averages: false
  metrics_set: "pascal_voc_detection_metrics"
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path:  "PATH_TO/data/pascal_label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 10
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "PATH_TO/data/pascal_val.record-?????-of-00010"
  }
}
```

The "pascal_voc_detection_metrics" don't seems to work either.

Comment: Can you also post your config file here, it is very important to find the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much - in my config I had num_classes: 90 so I hope num_classes: 824 will work now!

Comment: It is not only that, in `eval_config`, you should set `num_examples` to exactly the number of examples in your tfrecord file

Comment: Yes, I did set num_examples : 1886. However, tensorboard shows no results. How do I know the right logdir? Should I see the same short log results in the console when running model_main.py (train.py showed loss and time/step)?

Comment: the logdir is set by `--mode_dir` when you run `model_main.py`

Comment: Hi @danyfang! I corrected now the num_classes to 821 and corrected my lab map to these 821 classes. I recreated the TFRecord files and now Tensorboard shows me when evaluating with model_main the true groundtruth on the right images. However, I still get "the following classes have no ground truth examples" and in the images in Tensorboard no bounding boxes are detected on the left images. I will post now my config file since I cannot figure out why my model fails.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I managed to fix it. From your explanation, I have noticed that you have said you have 824 classes, but in your model .config file you have written 821 classes (in the num_classes parameter). This is the possible cause of the error. Make sure that the num_classes has the actual number of classes (824). I do hope the label_map file also reflects the same number of classes.
All the best.