# How to get my Faster R-CNN model with a custom dataset to actually detect objects?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

I converted my datatset with Pascal VOC style annotations to TFRecord file format and tried training a Faster R-CNN using a modified version of the config of Tensorflow's config in faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28.tar.gz

However, when running model_main.py I get the warning that almost all classees "have no ground truth examples"
(I posted this already here: [How to fix "the following classes have no ground truth examples" when running object_detection/model_main.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55904690/how-to-fix-the-following-classes-have-no-ground-truth-examples-when-running-ob)) 
and tensorboard shows the right ground truth in the images on the right hand side but no detections on the images on the left.

Why is my model not making any predictions and mAP=0? Maybe the problem is that I do not use a model from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md 
that already has Pascal mAP as metric?

---

This is my model .config file (with the right pathes of course):

```
model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 821
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 600
        max_dimension: 1024
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'faster_rcnn_inception_v2'
      first_stage_features_stride: 16
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        scales: [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        aspect_ratios: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        height_stride: 16
        width_stride: 16
      }
    }
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.01
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.7
    first_stage_max_proposals: 300
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    initial_crop_size: 14
    maxpool_kernel_size: 2
    maxpool_stride: 2
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 1.0
        fc_hyperparams {
          op: FC
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            variance_scaling_initializer {
              factor: 1.0
              uniform: true
              mode: FAN_AVG
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.0
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 300
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
  }
}
train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        manual_step_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0002
          schedule {
            step: 900000
            learning_rate: .00002
          }
          schedule {
            step: 1200000
            learning_rate: .000002
          }
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0
  #fine_tune_checkpoint: "PATH_TO/models/model/model.ckpt"
  #from_detection_checkpoint: true
  #load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars: true
  num_steps: 5000

  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_vertical_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_rotation90 {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "PATH_TO/data/pascal_label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path:"PATH_TO/data/pascal_train.record-?????-of-00010"
  }
}
eval_config {
  num_examples: 1886
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 100     evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 1886
  #use_moving_averages: false
  metrics_set: "pascal_voc_detection_metrics"
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path:  "PATH_TO/data/pascal_label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 10
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "PATH_TO/data/pascal_val.record-?????-of-00010"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I saw your last post as well and I wonder if you had any class names mispelled in your label map as you had 821 classes. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1936#issuecomment-377618785

Comment: Hi, probably not as I copy-pasted the automatically generated class names into the label map. But it is worth a try, and it was on my TODO list anyway to write a script that automatically generates the whole label map. I will let you know if it helped.

Comment: Hi @danyfang I wrote a scipt to generate pascal_label_map.pbtxt but now model_main even outputs that NO class has a ground truth example! In tensorboard the images on the right have the correct ground truth though but still no detections :(

Comment: I created the label map with: with open(os.path.join(FLAGS.output_path, "brands.txt"), newline = '') as brands: 
    brands_reader = csv.reader(brands, delimiter='\n')
    index=0
    with open(FLAGS.label_map_path, 'wb') as handle:
        for brand in brands_reader:
            index=index+1
            print(index,brand[0])
            handle.write(str.encode('item {\n','utf8'))
            handle.write(str.encode('  id: '+str(index)+'\n','utf8'))
            handle.write(str.encode('  name: \''+brand[0]+'\'\n','utf8'))
            handle.write(str.encode('}'+'\n\n','utf8'))

Comment: what is your dataset size? Since you have 821 classes, that would require a large dataset too. Can you try like detecting one or two classes at first

Comment: Hi @danyfang, That's a good idea. However, I only left 4 common class labels in the pascal_label_map.pbtxt and now in tensorboard no ground truth' are shown anymore. (The only 10 images which show up there do not contain the 4 classes indeed.) The scalars in tensorboard like "loss" and "maP" look similar to before, the first one going up and down, maP being 0...

Comment: These are the warnings I get: WARNING:root:image 927873815 does not have groundtruth difficult flag specified
WARNING:root:The following classes have no ground truth examples: [1 2 3 4]
WARNING:root:image 1213276280 does not have groundtruth difficult flag specified
WARNING:root:The following classes have no ground truth examples: [1 2 3 4]
WARNING:root:image 861196250 does not have groundtruth difficult flag specified
WARNING:root:The following classes have no ground truth examples: [1 2]
WARNING:root:image 366099435 does not have groundtruth difficult flag specified

Comment: WARNING:root:The following classes have no ground truth examples: [1 3 4]
WARNING:root:image 1036358333 does not have groundtruth difficult flag specified
WARNING:root:The following classes have no ground truth examples: [1 2 3 4]
WARNING:root:image 1236241709 does not have groundtruth difficult flag specified
WARNING:root:The following classes have no ground truth examples: [1 3 4]
WARNING:root:image 1982613351 does not have groundtruth difficult flag specified
WARNING:root:The following classes have no ground truth examples: [1 3 4]

Comment: Ah, training set is 6,034 images with annotations, validation set is 1,508 images with annotations (and separately, not used for model_main, the test set with 1,886 images+annotations)

Comment: In Tensorboard, one image with correct ground truth belonging to one of these 4 classes was now shown. Without detection on the left, though. So my model still seems to detect nothing...